# Browser based InfoPath form scrolling to top of page randomly

Tags: 2010, infopath, browser-compatibility

When users are filling out a web enabled InfoPath 2010 form on my company's SharePoint site there are times that the form will automatically scroll to the top of the page. The user checks a box and suddenly the form is at the top of the page, completely away from the area they were filling out.

Why is this? I have rules and XPath on the form; there are many repeating sections. What is a common cause for form scrolling without user input?

Is the form somehow putting the text cursor in a different location on the page?

This scrolling behavior does not occur when using InfoPath 2010 on the client system.

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue as well on one of my forms, and I found setting the Tab Indexes on each control fixed the scrolling.

Comment: I agree that you should explicitly define Tab index: (< Advanced < Control properties) order since all indexes are set on creation to 0

Comment: I think this is the answer; @Chris, did this work for you?

Comment: Apologies for the long response time. This mitigated the issue but did not resolve it. Real pain... It appears that this issue is native only to IE7 and IE8. Our corporate standard happens to be IE7 at the moment (ugh) and so I don't know if there is any way around it. Would setting the tab indices to -1 resolve the issue?

Comment: One additional thing; this appears to be caused by an incorrect setting in the "MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback" setting on the InfoPath web enabled form. Is there any way to change this?

Answer (score 0):

If [setting the indexes](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/50011/8319) does not work, you can try to set hidden textbox and in codebehind **Loading Event** (in Infopath Designer on Ribbon click the button with such title under **Developer** tab) handler [use SelectNode or SelectText to jump](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb251012%28v=office.12%29.aspx) to this hidden textbox control on form loading.

Comment: Gennady, thanks - unfortunately I cannot use any custom code on the form. It's strictly forbidden on my domain :P Wish I could explore your suggestion!